# Inaccurate Time-O-Lite - How to adjust?

Tags: darkroom

I bought a lightly used Time-O-Lite, but it always runs about 5 seconds longer than the number reads. At 0 seconds, it runs about 5 seconds. At 10 it runs for 15, etc. The screw inside the red needle head looked stripped, so I bought another one. This one is also off, and goes 1.5 seconds longer than it should. The screw inside this needle head also does not seem to have any threads for a screw driver. How can I adjust the needle to make sure the Time O Lite is accurate?

Answer (score 1):

A hack solution:  Bend the needle.

Another hack:  Cut an arrow out of white cardboard and attach with carpet tape to the present needle. Then use a black marker and blacken the regular needle

Non hack

I'm not familiar with this particular timer.  Open the box. (Unplug first)

There is probably a cam mounted on the same shaft as the needle that at the end of the time opens a circuit.  This cam is likely secured to the shaft with a screw.  Undo the screw to adjust the cam.

If it's electronic inside you're hooped.